# Disabling HTTPS redirection for migration

Tags: redirect, ssl

I migrated a WordPress 4.3 site from Register.com to MediaTemple today and found that the forced SSL is causing issues for the staging URL.

In order to try again I have (on the live Register.com site)

- Disabled plugin 'WordPress HTTPS'
- Removed `define( 'FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true );` from wp-config
- In General Settings replaced https w http for URLs and saved
- Saved permalinks just in case
- verified that .htaccess is not redirecting to https via mod_rewrite

Tried logging out and accessing site and still get redirected from http to https.

Assuming my predecessor has not done anything truly crazy what am I missing there?  Where should I look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the active theme I found the redirection in header.php

Once commented out the issue was resolved.

```
if($_SERVER["HTTPS"] != "on")
{
    header("Location: https://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
   exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after a migration on staging local environnent, I resolved it by emptying the cache with a hard refresh.